# How to add columns to a pivot table of external data source in Excel (VBA)?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a Pivot Table with an external data source. Now I need a couple of columns of values that I don't get from the source.

Data:

```
Amount | Mo | Tu | We | Th | Fr
3        1    0    0    1    1
```

Now I need all of the columns with the value multiplied with `0.2`.

This columns should be added:

```
mAmount | mMo | mTu | mWe | mTh | mFr
0.6       0.2   0     0     0.2   0.2
```

I know I can double click the Pivot Table and add a column and give it a formula like `=[@[mo]]*0.2`, but as far as I know it's not possible to refresh the table that's obtained with the double click.

Is it possible to add columns of data to the pivot table or am I thinking too hard?

Comment: *but as far as I know it's not possible to refresh the table that's obtained with the double click* - once you refresh the pivot table, the calculated columns will update as well.

Comment: Use Pivot Table Calculated Field. http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-calculated-field.html

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Truly? The columns on another sheet will change when I refresh the pivot table on the main sheet?

Comment: @Grafit - Add a calculated field to the pivot table, then it will refresh with the pivot table. I thought you understood calculated fields when you wrote: `I know I can double click the Pivot Table and add a column and give it a formula `, but now I see you meant something different. My bad.